# Search one file's lines for a partial match in another file

Tags: awk, command-line, grep

I have 2 files, the first one:

values.txt

```
test@
test1@
test3@
test4@
test6@
test7@    
test8@
test9@
test10@
```

data.csv

```
"username","email"
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user456","loka@gmail.com"
"user789","lopa@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user","xpos@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
"user","xpx@gmail.com"
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

What I was able to do :

```
$ awk -F, -v q='"' 'NR==FNR{a[q $0 q]; next} 
                    $2 in a' values.txt data.csv > test1.csv
```

This will work only when i have the full "email" exp: `test9@gmail.com` and not only `test9@` a new file test1.csv containing:

```
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
 ....
 ....
```

Couldn't figure out how to do it with a partial substring with awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {ea = $2; gsub(/^"|@.*$/, "", ea)} ea "@" in a' values.txt data.csv

"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {
   a[$1]                   # from values.txt store each value in array a
   next
}
{
   ea = $2                 # copy $2 into ea (email address)
   gsub(/^"|@.*$/, "", ea) # strip starting " and text after @
}
ea "@" in a                # check if ea + "@" exists in array a
' values.txt data.csv
```

Comment: Thank you that did the job like intended :) could you just exmplain me the purpose of ea please ?

Comment: I have added an expalantion

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Looks like few of your lines have empty spaces at last of the lines in case you want to remove them and then match both the file's contents I have added `gsub(/ +$/,"")` in my solution.

```
awk '
{ gsub(/ +$/,"") }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(key in arr){
    if(index($2,key)){
      print
      next
    }
  }
}' values.txt FS="," delta.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
{ gsub(/ +$/,"") }                  ##Using gsub to remove spaces at last of lines.
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when values.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]                           ##Creating arr here with index of current line value.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(key in arr){                  ##Going through arr elements from here.
    if(index($2,key)){              ##Checking condition if key is present by index in 2nd field.
      print                         ##Printing the current line.
      next                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
    }
  }
}' values.txt FS="," delta.csv      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```